# loop and modular operation in R

Tags: r, loops

I want to make such a loop using R.

for i=1 output will be

```
1
2
3
```

for i=2 output will be

```
2
3
1
```

for i=3 output will be

```
3
1
2
```

Namely the outputs are successive integers. It is just when the integer reaches 4 it returns 1 and goes on. I guess I must use modular operations, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have

```
a <- 1:3
```

for a value if `i`, you get the the sequence with

```
f <- function(i) (a+i+1) %% length(a) +1
f(1)
# [1] 1 2 3
f(2)
# [1] 2 3 1
f(3)
# [1] 3 1 2
f(4)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Note that it starts over again at 4

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution:

```
f <- function(i) { x <- i:(i+2) %% 3; x[x==0] <- 3; x }
for (i in 1:5) print(f(i))
```

Here is a second solution:

```
r <- matrix(c(3,1,2, 1,2,3, 2,3,1),3)
for (i in 1:5) print(r[i %% 3 + 1,])
```